# How to access Google Map API v3 features loaded using loadGeoJson()

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geojson

I'm working with the Google Maps API, and trying to access the features loaded using loadGeoJson(). The documentation seems to suggest that map.data.forEach(function(feature)) should be able to loop through all of the features. But when I load data using loadGeoJson, it creates pins on the map without appearing to create any features in the data.

Example: http://www.wittprojects.net/dev/overflow/load_no_features.php 
My code tries outputting the feature data to console.log (see below), so if you visit that page and open the developer tools you'll be able to see the various ways that attempting to access the data fails.

Here's my map code:

```
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 40.397, lng: 0.644},
    zoom: 6
  });

  var json = 'overflow.geojson';
  map.data.loadGeoJson(json);
  console.log("Logging the data features:");
  console.log(map.data.features);
  console.log("Using map.data.forEach:");
  map.data.forEach(function(feature) {
  });
  console.log("Here's the whole map object:");
  console.log(map);
}
```

And the GeoJson it's loading: http://www.wittprojects.net/dev/overflow/overflow.geojson

```
{  
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "features":[  
      {  
         "properties":{  
            "name":"Toledo",
            "traveler":6
         },
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{  
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[  
               -3.9853,
               39.8208
            ]
         }
      },
      {  
         "properties":{  
            "name":"Madrid",
            "traveler":6
         },
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{  
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[  
               -3.665398,
               40.373363
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Where is my data going?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.loadGeoJson](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/data#loadGeoJson) is asynchronous.  You need wait for the callback to run before the data will be available.

from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/data#loadGeoJson)

> loadGeoJson(url[, options, callback])
>   **Parameters:**
>   url:  string
>   options (optional):  Data.GeoJsonOptions
>   callback (optional):  function(Array)
>   Return Value:  None
>   Loads GeoJSON from a URL, and adds the features to the collection.
>   NOTE: The GeoJSON is fetched using XHR, and may not work cross-domain. If you have issues, we recommend you fetch the GeoJSON using your choice of AJAX library, and then call addGeoJson().

```
map.data.loadGeoJson('https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/google.json', {}, function(features) {
  console.log("Logging the data features:");
  // note that there is no map.data.features property, but the callback returns the array of added features
  console.log(map.data.features); // == undefined
  console.log(features); // array of added features
  console.log("Using map.data.forEach:");
  map.data.forEach(function(feature) {
    console.log(feature);
  });
});
```

Or you can use the `features` array passed in the callback function:

```
map.data.loadGeoJson('https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/google.json', {}, function(features) {
  console.log("Logging the data features:");
  console.log(features);
  console.log("Using map.data.forEach:");
  features.forEach(function(feature) {
    console.log(feature);
  });
})
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/e6q9ymja/8/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -28,
      lng: 137
    },
    zoom: 4
  });

  map.data.loadGeoJson('https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/google.json', {}, function(features) {
    console.log("Logging the data features:");
    // note that there is no map.data.features property, but the callback returns the array of added features
    console.log(features);
    console.log("Using map.data.forEach:");
    map.data.forEach(function(feature) {
      console.log(feature);
    });
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```